# Mozilla Thunderbird: New email, but I can't see it

Tags: thunderbird

Very often I see a tooltip on my desktop saying that that I have new email in my inbox, but when I bring Thunderbird back into focus (I have the program always open), I see that:

- My Inbox folder is displayed correctly with **Inbox(1)** .
- However, the new mail is not shown in scrollable list of emails.
- When I type <kbd>n</kbd> Thunderbird fails to take me to the new mail

I have tried pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-F5</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-Home</kbd> and similar keys to refresh the list of emails, but nothing works. The only way I can see the new mail is by clicking on a different folder (e.g. **Sent**), and then go back to **Inbox**.

Is there a way to get Thunderbird to refresh the list of emails (from the keyboard) when this happens?

This is all on Thunderbird 15.0.1 (latest version) on Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Check this link http://kb.mozillazine.org/New_messages_do_not_appear